# Looking for a word to describe "all" of a given book: all printings, all editions, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

So I've come across this problem when constructing a database schema.

So an individual book is a book ("copy 101 of the first printing of the first edition of Catcher in the Rye").

An individual print of a book, is a print of a book ("any individual book belonging the first printing of the first edition of Catcher in the Rye").

An individual edition of a book, is an edition of a book ("any individual book belonging to the first edition of Catcher in the Rye").

But I can't seem to find a term to describe all of the above ("any individual book which is Catcher in the Rye"). Basically this is to avoid double-counting in the database-- if an individual copy is an instance of a book, and the collection of all books of that kind is also an instance of a book, then they'd be counted twice which would mess up totals. A compound word or phrase would be acceptable in this case, just to differentiate an individual book and all books of that "type".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: a "title", maybe?

Comment: I think that the best you can do without pre-defining stipulative definitions is 'total number of copies of this book printed to date'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requests for help in naming things in software is specifically off-topic in according to our [help].

Comment: @tchrist oh my gosh, I am so sorry; I missed that in the question posting guidelines; won't make the same mistake again!

Comment: I beilieve it's called a *work*.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [**title**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/title)

> a usually published work as distinguished from a particular copy.
> "published 25 new titles" (Merriam-Webster)

Two different editions of a book would still be the same title, as would two different prints.

Comment: If a book is republished with a different title, is it still the same title?